# Non-passive event Google Chart API JS

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

*Short question:*

How to remove *mousewheel event* using **google chart API** or make it passive?

---

I use [google chart api](https://developers.google.com/chart). On my website, I draw a **[SteppedAreaChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart)**. I declare it like this on my script:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(myArray);

var options = {
    title: 'Title',
    vAxis: { title: 'kg' },
    hAxis: { title: "m/s" },
    isStacked: true,
    enableInteractivity: false
};

var chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, options);
```

---

The chart displays very well on the screen. However, I ran into this error when **updating the chart**:

[image: Error on my browser console.]

---

The error seems to be raise when I call the **`chart.draw(...)` method**. I constantly update data and so I *frequently call this method* to draw the chart with new data. Maybe the browser dislike being overload by google maps' mousewheel events.

Looking after useless events, I tried to **remove the tooltip** over the chart but it does not work. I do not find *any topic on the subject*. Moreover, I do not find any mention about mousewheel event on [google chart documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visdraw).

Is it a way to *delete this mousewheel event* or call it as a *passive* one?

---

*Tell me if you have any questions or comments.*

Comment: it's not an error, _Console Violations remind you of best practices, customized to your code._ -- and in this case, not your code, the google charts api code. see [Chrome DevTools](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/192-console-violations/) -- probably not something you can fix...